# SQL Error on index view after database creation with EF and MVC (Cascading delete issue)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've seen some similar problems but I am not sure what is causing the cascading delete issue. These are my classes:

```
    public class Game
    {
        [Key]
        public int GameID { get; set; }
        public int GenreID { get; set; }
        public int ConsoleID { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public Console Console { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }

    public class Console
    {
        [Key]
        public int ConsoleID { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }

    }

    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
        public List<Console> Consoles { get; set; }
    }
`
    public class Genre
    {
        [Key]
        public int GenreID { get; set; }
        public int GenreTypeID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } 
        public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
        public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public List<Serie> Series { get; set; }
    }

    public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int GenreID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    }

    public class Serie
    {
        [Key]
        public int SerieID { get; set; }
        public int GenreID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    }
```

I'm getting the error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Games_dbo.Consoles_ConsoleID' on table 'Games' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

I then added the following to stop cascade deletes to Genres, Companies and Consoles when deleting a game:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
      .HasRequired(x => x.Console)
      .WithRequiredPrincipal()
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
      .HasRequired(x => x.Genre)
      .WithRequiredPrincipal()
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
      .HasRequired(x => x.Company)
      .WithRequiredPrincipal()
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
  }
```

Now I get the following error when trying to seed my Database with some simple data: `{"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Consoles_dbo.Companies_CompanyID\". The conflict occurred in database \"GAMES_f8b82655d5bd4f0db9cee85535197d4c\", table \"dbo.Companies\", column 'CompanyID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`

What is meant by this? The seeding data is as follows:

```
Game game = new Game
                {
                    GenreID = 1,
                    ConsoleID = 1,
                    CompanyID = 2,
                    Title = "Final Fantasy I",
                    Description = "Blabla",
                    ReleaseDate = new DateTime(1986, 1, 1)

                };
                db.Games.Add(game);
                db.SaveChanges();

                Game game2 = new Game
                {
                    GenreID = 1,
                    ConsoleID = 2,
                    CompanyID = 2,
                    Title = "Final Fantasy VII",
                    Description = "Blabla",
                    ReleaseDate = new DateTime(1986, 2, 2)
                };
                db.Games.Add(game2);
                db.SaveChanges();

                Models.Console console = new Models.Console
                {
                    CompanyID = 3,
                    Title = "NES",
                    ReleaseDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1)
                };
                db.Consoles.Add(console);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

The error happens when calling the last SaveChanges. I thought it could be because a company with this id does not exist yet. But the same can be said for the foreign keys on the Game object. I also only added the SaveChanges method after every object I add to see on which object the error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

When I created a database based on the above code, I noticed that the foreign keys seemed to appear twice within some of the classes. Therefore, I removed explicit references to the foreign keys within the classes. I was able to get the seed method to run by making the following changes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Context db = new Context();

    Company company = new Company{};

    Genre genre = new Genre
    {
        GenreTypeID = 1
    };

    Console console = new Console
    {
        Title = "NES",
        ReleaseDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1),
    };
    db.Consoles.Add(console);

    Game game = new Game
    {
        Company = company,
        Console = console,
        Genre = genre,
        Title = "Final Fantasy I",
        Description = "Blabla",
        ReleaseDate = new DateTime(1986, 1, 1)

    };
    db.Games.Add(game);

    Game game2 = new Game
    {
        Company = company,
        Console = console,
        Genre = genre,
        Title = "Final Fantasy VII",
        Description = "Blabla",
        ReleaseDate = new DateTime(1986, 2, 2)
    };
    db.Games.Add(game2);

    db.SaveChanges();

}

public class Game
{
    [Key]
    public int GameID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public Console Console { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Console
{
    [Key]
    public int ConsoleID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

}

public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public List<Console> Consoles { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    [Key]
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public int GenreTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } 
    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public List<Serie> Series { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In regards to question 1: Why does it cascade delete. Because that is the default for EF when creating the database from your classes.

Question 2: What does the error mean? It means you do not have a company with an id of 3.

```
Models.Console console = new Models.Console
            {
                // no company here
                CompanyID = 3, 
                Title = "NES",
                ReleaseDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1)
            };
```

As a note: when performing more than 1 related database action at a time, only call SaveChanges at the end. No actual database updates happen until this time and it will then have all the related data it needs. If you call SaveChanges after each step (which I realize you did for testing) it will require any related data to exist already.